# UnsatisfiedLinkError when invoking JProfiler

Tags: java, jenkins, jprofiler

I am trying to Integrate Jprofiler 8.1.4 with jenkins using offline profiling API of JProfiler.
Below is the program written to

- Start JProfiler Recording.
- Save Snapshot.
- Stop JProfiler Recording.

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;

  public class TestJenJPIntegration {
      public static Connection connObj = null;
      public static void recordCPUdata() throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException{

  ```
      File fileObj;
      fileObj = new File("C:\\Perl\\firstSnap.jps");
      Controller.startCPURecording(true);
              System.out.println("CPU recording started..");

                 Controller.saveSnapshot(fileObj);
      System.out.println("Saved snapshot");

                 Controller.stopCPURecording();
      System.out.println("CPU recording stopped..");    

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {

          recordCPUdata();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
  ```

  }

The Jprofiler tool works fine manually to start recording, save snapshot and stop recording. But when i Execute the Program I get the following Error Message UnsatisfiedLinkError :

- I used the Demo Server Profiling which was available in the JProfiler itself. And I am Profiling in the same system where the Demo Application runs.
- **NOTE: The server and client are using the same JProfilerTI.dll would this be a problem.**

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.jprofiler.agent.InterceptionCallee.registerI
    nterceptions0(Z[Lcom/jprofiler/agent/util/h;Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;Ljava/lang/
    reflect/Field;Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;Ljava/lang/refle
    ct/Field;Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;Ljava/lang/reflect/Fi
    eld;Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/la
    ng/reflect/Method;)V
            at com.jprofiler.agent.InterceptionCallee.registerInterceptions0(Native
    Method)
            at com.jprofiler.agent.InterceptionCallee.registerInterceptions(ejt:152)

```
        at com.jprofiler.agent.probe.y.a(ejt:181)
        at com.jprofiler.agent.probe.y.a(ejt:37)
        at com.jprofiler.agent.Agent.initStatic(ejt:320)
        at com.jprofiler.agent.Agent.<clinit>(ejt:98)
        at com.jprofiler.agent.ControllerImpl.startCPURecording(ejt:53)
        at com.jprofiler.api.agent.Controller.startCPURecording(ejt:108)
        at TestJenJPIntegration.recordCPUdata(TestJenJPIntegration.java:24)
        at TestJenJPIntegration.main(TestJenJPIntegration.java:45)
JProfiler> Native library not found. Ignoring controller call.
```

/*Users Printed Statement*/

```
CPU recording started..

Exception in thread "_jprofiler_offline_comm" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: co
m.jprofiler.agent.ControllerImpl.saveSnapshot0([BLjava/lang/Object;)V
        at com.jprofiler.agent.ControllerImpl.saveSnapshot0(Native Method)
        at com.jprofiler.agent.ControllerImpl.access$100(ejt:18)
        at com.jprofiler.agent.h.run(ejt:186)
```

/*Users Printed Statement*/  `Saved snapshot`

```
JProfiler> Native library not found. Ignoring controller call.
```

/*Users Printed Statement*/  `CPU recording stopped..`

Answer (score 0):

The com.jprofiler.api.platform are not intended for offline profiling, but for writing a program that analyzes the profiling data directly. You should only use the Controller class and pass the -agentpath VM parameter with the offline switch as given by the integration wizard

Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration

Comment: My problem is I am unble to start Recording using the above program for Jprofiler.
Now I tried to load the System.loadLibrary in my program the JVM got crashed.

# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000001800719bd, pid=3844, t
id=5352
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_60-b19) (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client vers
ions of Windows.

Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried the integration wizard? You cannot use loadLibrary, you must pass an -agentpath VM parameter as given by the integration wizard

Comment: No, the Controller invocation has to be made in your code that is running in the profiled JVM, you never need to load the JProfiler library manually. There is no separate JProfiler process unless you mean the JProfiler GUI which is not relevant for offline profiling.

Comment: Sorry mistakenly i added that.. Now please check my code

Comment: Have you added the -agentpath VM parameter and do you get an lines prefixed with "JProfiler>" when you start the program? Because if not, it's not going to work.